# Interpreting MySQL database integer values

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, binary, bit

I was wondering what might be the best solution to my problem. I have a MySQL database that I am reading from in my DataGridView. One of my columns logs Integer values. However, the current values are not exactly correct.

For instance, suppose I have this column with one row instance with a value of 128. As a binary representation, 128 is 10000000. Still, this is not exactly what I want. What I want to do is to split this value into particular sections and check to see if a particular section is 0, if it is NOT, then log THAT value, rather than 128.

So, if I have 128 and I want to split the binary string of 10000000 into the following parts
10 000 000 
Starting from the end of the string and working my way to the front, I will check the values. So the first subset is 0, so nothing of note there, the next is also 0. However, the third section is, as a standalone, 01, which is 2 in binary. THAT's what I would like to display on my DataGridView, rather than the existing 128.

One additional problem is, not all the values will be easy like 128. Some of them might be like 41160 which is 1010000011001000. The split will be something like
1 0001 00011 001 000

For reference, the split is like this for a 32 bit, starting from the end:
3, 3, 5, 4, 4, and then the leftovers.

I know this sounds a bit confusing, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I do not understand what you're trying to do?! How can an integer value not be correct? Do you want so set single bits in a 32/64/128 integer and check if the Nth bit is set?

Comment: Basically I want to scan through a binary string representation of an integer, if a section is 0, skip it..and for a section that isn't 0, modify the database value to display on screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer division and the modulus operator to extract digit ranges from numbers.

The general form is `(number / (radix^digits_to_cut)) % (radix^digits_to_show)`.

Example for MySQL (you can do the same in c#):

```
select 
t.col,
t.col % 0b1000 as a,
t.col div 0b1000 % 0b1000  as b,
t.col div 0b1000000 % 0b100000 as c,
t.col div 0b100000000000 % 0b10000 as d,
t.col div 0b1000000000000000 % 0b10000 as е
from (select 0b1010000011001000+0 as col) as t
```

This works for every radix and range, you just need to adjust the constants.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, honestly. I am using a String in my C# code for my query.